# Derive the type from the return value of the function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Assume we have a DogUser and a CatUser.
Is it possible to derive DogUser or CatUser when narrowing by user name from an array? (without using user type defined guard)
I think I can write it using Conditional Types, but not sure how to write it.

```js
type Dog = 'dog'
type Cat = 'cat';

interface User {
    name: string;
}

interface DogUser extends User {
    pet: Dog;
}

interface CatUser extends User {
    pet: Cat;
}

const u1: DogUser = {
    name: 'foo',
    pet: 'dog'
}

const u2: CatUser = {
    name: 'bar',
    pet: 'cat'
}

const getUserByName = (users: Array<DogUser | CatUser>, name: string) => {
    const user = users.find((user) => user.name === name);
    if (user!.pet === 'dog') { // just suppose user will not be undefined.
        return user as DogUser; // I know this way of writing won't work, but I want to derive it here.
    } else {
        return user as CatUser; // ditto.
    } 
}

const users = [u1, u2]
// I want this `u` to be the type either of DogUser or CatUser
const u = getUserByName(users, 'bar');

const foo = (user: DogUser) => {
  console.log(user)
}

foo(u); // <= ts compile error

// user type defied guard can work, but without this.
// const isDog = (p: DogUser | CatUser): p is DogUser => {
//     return p.pet === 'dog'
// }
// if (isDog(u)) {
//     foo(u)
// }
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=50&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcygXigcgCaLQKFJKAYQENgV0BjUtAbhxwEsA7YCAJwDNiLoBVAZ3ZQA3jijioTYgFsIALij9gbZgjoBfes1adu0eAgFCIAD1ZMM-KEbYixEyMAUGNWluy48ipG1FPnLa0FbUQkoRwUSYFccCjgmJSgAVwBGZ0RfVFCJKVkFNA44ODQAGntxCPQsBFxNWPjEpIAmSJ9g8mzxXPl0ACNiNlLy8IgnSmocOriEsgRRmwAhEAA5GWhUAAok4P4FAEE2NmIQAB4DXwAfb2AbAD4SyTWFJRUmBABKFFu7MOnG9tQ23Y-AAdBxmBgNltgp9kN8gWwQd0UMhUN13nQwgwOFBoewAIQgxwo1CYbCfYRQAD0VKgACttmR%20EkwGA4IJku0AO4MAA2vMkcDIvWgSQsEHBTAgGBBwzCbFGSTYTE5QmIVnOwRo1NpwAAFgwrFgIPwmGgyFy4GwANbDdR%20XkczphKAK4BKlUIqDq642bU0qD6w1QY2m81QS02wNFO1QSb0P5kBFWVAAbVSD2aAF16jNkuQ5jdgktVrI8Wx%20A80P1BhiEw0yIU4ORy%20lDDCvj8oH84LyICDeYhy%2094zgm1s6zgA178NAMBKGNKoAgkgMMN3iCrI9aHr0khaGPq4PvAwbQVPaYmoIaDC2wG3Lr6YQowNeNRkAd9RAH5YrleEiVGEkqmwC8oE0ANsVxG8hySd4KTAsJxzgsDNCAA)

Comment: `getUserByName` still returns `DogUser | CatUser`. Your type assertion does not exist at runtime, so TS cannot say for sure what the type returned would be.

Comment: yes, I want to narrow the type.

Comment: Well, you cannot do it this way because the type assertion doesn't influence the return type. `y = getUserByName(x, name)` will produce a union because each branch can produce either. You're mixing up compilation time knowledge with runtime knowledge - at compile time you *don't know* what exactly `y` would be. You can use a type guard *on `y`* afterwards, however.